# In Flutter the VS Code editor throws an error - The function 'myApp' isn't defined

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am very beginner in flutter and dart, I just created my app and as it automatically creates a template app, It throws an error in widget_test.dart file in test folder

```
The function 'myApp' isn't defined.
Try importing the library that defines 'myApp', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'myApp'.
```

```json
{
    "resource": "/D:/development/hello_rectangle/test/widget_test.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": "undefined_function",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The function 'myApp' isn't defined.\nTry importing the library that defines 'myApp', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'myApp'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 16,
    "startColumn": 29,
    "endLineNumber": 16,
    "endColumn": 34,
    "tags": []
}
```

I've tried upgrading flutter but it won't work!!

Comment: Have you followed installing and setup flutter step by step?

Comment: Yes, I did. I had recently ran several apps for practice purpose, I have no Idea how this error caused in this default template code!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably **running test for application**.

You may change code of default application and it start giving error.

you can simply delete that file to avoid test application or you can create test for application.

To learn more about test in flutter click: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing

Comment: Hello there, Thanks. I deleted the test file and the error vanished , but will there be any problem after deletion of that test file?

Comment: test file is used to develop test case for application, when you develop any application and you want to make test programatically then you can use it. if you don't want to test that way then it doesn’t affect your application in any way.

Comment: Thankyou for your support, is there any video tutorial which will cover the concept of widget_test.dart file ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75i5VmTI6A0&t=134s this tutorial is nice but if you are new to flutter then i think you can avoid testing in beginning. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you create a new project, pre-written code is available in the `main.dart` file, which helps a new user to test code that they don't understand, but when we want to create something from scratch, `MyApp()` is defined in a test file whose location is under Project  , just tap on downward arrow just near the Project and you will see test file , open it and delete  `widget_test.dart file`

Once you delete the `widget_test.dart file`, the error disappears.